# Find element by data-id and get left style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So instead of hardcoding my fillRect I want it to take the left style directly from the region tag. If it had an **id** I would just do like this:

```
var testIdLeft = document.getElementById("testId").style.left
```

So it would look something like this:

```
fillRect(testIdLeft, 0, 100, 20)
```

But I dont know how to do it with data-attribute I think its called. S**o what I want to do is to get the left style from each region tag and input it in my fillRects.**

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(38,0,100,20);

var ctz = c.getContext("2d");
ctz.fillStyle = "FF0000";
ctz.fillRect(100,22, 100, 20);
```

```css
canvas {
  margin-left:-8px;
  
}
```

```html
<region class="wavesurfer-region" title="0:01-0:02" data-id="1" style="position: absolute; z-index: 2; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 38px; width: 1px; cursor: default; background-color: rgb(25, 170, 141);"></region>
<region class="wavesurfer-region" title="0:05-0:05" data-id="2" style="position: absolute; z-index: 2; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 100px; width: 1px; cursor: default; background-color: rgb(25, 170, 141);"></region>



<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500%" height="100%" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
```

Comment: You can find an element by data-id:
$("[data-id='" + YourId + "']");

Comment: Can you include your html for 'testId', including the data attribute.

Comment: It's not clear what relevance the 'myCanvas' stuff is to the question.

Comment: @CyrilIselin and how do I get the left attribute?

Comment: @freedomn-m u need canvas to draw inside it please check the code snippet. I just gave an example with testId....

Comment: @Dollerup that's why you need to include your html markup - we don't know what you've called "the left attribute" - could be `data-left=` or `left=` or from the style (ie not an attribute at all)

Comment: Please check the region tag.I want its left style.

Comment: The question is about retrieving an "attribute" (which may or may not be an attribute) - how you use that (ie in the canvas) isn't relevant.  There's no "testid" in the canvas (unless I'm totally missing something).

Comment: testId is just an example how I would do it if the regions had "id" I want to get the left style from my region tags. But I dont know how to find the left attribute since the regions dont have a "id" just a "data-id"

Comment: @dollerup:
console.log($("[data-id='1']").css("left"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery to get elements based on their data attribute, eg:

```
$("[data-id='" + id + "']")
```

And then you can use `.get(0)` to get the DOM version of the jquery object, which then allows you to use 'pure' javascript as before:

```
$("[data-id='" + id + "']").get(0).style.left;
```

Example for code in the question:

```
$("[data-id='1']").get(0).style.left;
```

Alternatively, you can keep with jquery:

```
$("[data-id='" + id + "']").position().left;
$("[data-id='" + id + "']").offset().left;
```

Whether you use `position` or `offset`, depends on your requirements, check the doc for more info: http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Comment: Thanks this worked. Is there any way to only get the numbers? Because `$("[data-id='1']").get(0).style.left;` gives me "38px". Ofc I can use substring(0,2) but it wont work if its like 100px.

Comment: Did you try either of the alternatives?  or you can use `parseInt(val, 10)` which will ignore the "px"